# JSON Print results from $_POST Method

Tags: php, json

When I am getting results am getting the results in array format, this is preventing me to post the values in required format.

I need my results in the required format (These inputs am getting from while loop):

```
<html>
<form>
<input type=text name=ref_id[] value=abc>
<input type=text name=qty[] value=12>
<input type=submit name=submit>
```

PHP Script:

```
$data1 = array(
'delv_num' => $delv_num,
'hu_id' => $hu_id,
'box_scan_value' => $box_scan_value,
'type' => $type,
'hu_detail'=> array(
'reference_id'=> $_POST['ref_id'],
'qty' => $_POST['qty'] )
  );
echo json_encode($data1);
```

Am getting Results as follows:

```
{
"delv_num":"0006020715",
"hu_id":"HU000000000000000225",
"box_scan_value":"68889",
"type":"box",
"hu_detail":{
"reference_id":["TD0000000000991","TD0000000000990","TD0000000000767"],
"qty":["2","0","0"]
}
}
```

But I need results in this following format:

```
{
"delv_num":"0006020715",
"hu_id":"HU000000000000000225",
"box_scan_value":"68889",
"type":"box",
"hu_detail":[{
"reference_id":"TD0000000000991",
"qty":"2"
},
{
"reference_id":"TD0000000000990",
"qty":"0"
},
{
"reference_id":"TD0000000000767",
"qty":"0"
}
]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What prevents you building the desired data structure? You probably need to learn more about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). It's a long page but it contains all the answers you need.

Comment: I read that, it didn't help to my query.

Comment: Then read it again. Hint: use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over `$_POST['ref_id']` and build the list to put in `'hu_details'`, don't put `$_POST['ref_id']` as is in your destination object.

Comment: Create 3 array as $data1, $data2, $data3 and pass them correnpondence values and last merge the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by your own. If not, you should go through php-basics again:

```
$complete = [
    'delv_num'       => $delv_num,
    'hu_id'          => $hu_id,
    'box_scan_value' => $box_scan_value,
    'type'           => $type,
    'hu_detail' => []
];
foreach ($_POST['ref_id'] as $index => $refId) {
    $huDetail = [
        'reference_id'=> $refId,
        'qty' => $_POST['qty'][$index]
    ];
    $complete['hu_detail'][] = $huDetail;
}

echo json_encode($complete);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the structure of the form by changing the name of the inputs

```
<input type="text" name="hu_detail[0][reference_id]" value="abc">
<input type="text" name="hu_detail[0][qty]" value="12">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$references =  $_POST['ref_id'];
$qtys = $_POST['qty'];

$data = array(
'delv_num' => $delv_num,
'hu_id' => $hu_id,
'box_scan_value' => $box_scan_value,
'type' => $type,
);

$huDetails = [];

foreach($references as $index => $ref){
   $huDetails[$index]['ref'] = $ref;
   $huDetails[$index]['qty'] = $qtys[$index]; //assuming you have `ref` and `qty` has same number of index, if not then you need to modify your html structure
}

$data['hu_details'] = $huDetails;

print_r(json_encode($data))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$result = array();
$array_a = array("1","2","3");

$array_b = array("test1","test2","test3");

foreach($array_a as $key=> $value){
  $result[$key]['reference_id'] = $value;
  $result[$key]['qty'] = $array_b[$key];
}

$myJSONString = json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution in a single statement:

```
$data1 = [
    'delv_num' => $delv_num,
    'hu_id' => $hu_id,
    'box_scan_value' => $box_scan_value,
    'type' => $type,
    'hu_detail' => array_map(
         function ($id, $qty) {
             return ['reference_id': $id, 'qty': $qty];
         },
         $_POST['ref_id'],
         $_POST['qty']
    ),
];
```